# uiview with uiimage as background

Tags: iphone, objective-c

u build an UIView and put an image as the view backgrond:

```
self.tmpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 70, 280, 295)];  
self.tmpView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

self.tmpView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tmpView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CloseUPPicBG.png"]];
```

the problem is that theuiview is now with corners in black color.
the image that i put as backgrond is with rounded corners.

any solution for this?

Comment: The view should be autoreleased if its a property with the attr. nonatomic, retain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the image to not have rounded corners, or so that the space behind the corners is some other color or image.

What you're doing is saying

```
View, be yellow.
View, be clear. What's behind you? Nothing. Ok, be black.
View, fill yourself with this image.
```

View is then thinking

```
Hmm... there's transparency in this image.
Guess I should show whatever's behind me. Which is nothing... So black.
```

Comment: change the actual image resource to **not have rounded corners**.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tmpView.opaque = NO;
```

might help.